# Django - Edit admin content without overwriting previous data

Tags: django

Assuming I am creating an admin page with below model.

```
class Person(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()
     about = models.TextField()
```

Now, I have saved below content in "about" field.

"I am a programmer."

Again, I would like to append additional data without overwriting the above data.

"I am a programmer. I like to code."

I appending the data pragmatically. However, it just overwrites the previous data and writes the new one. So I end up having this in about field.

"I like to code."

Comment: How are you "appending the data programatically" exactly?

Comment: Just defining a model doesn't create an admin page, you have to separately register the model in an `admin.py` as detailed here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: You need to show us the code where you are trying to append the data, so we can see what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should explain how you append the data.
Generally, you can easily automatically append data to the Django Model using a save def in the Model declaration.
See here for more information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

Comment: John, this is what exactly I am doing. I am using save def to modify the content before saving. But what happens is, when I do a for loop, the 2nd data replaces the 1st data. Example,

for i in ['a', 'b']:
   self.number = i

1st time it saves a, but 2nd time it just replaces with b. But I want to insert b, so I can retain both a and b value, rather overwriting previous content.

Comment: I have found a way to do this. We should not iterate the loop within model. Rather store the list with json encoded. Then retrieve the list back, decode the json and then iterate it in the template. This gives me the output I expected.

Yuval and Anentropic, I am sorry that I wasn't much clear in my question. I appreciate all of your help on this.